# What is the MSbuild/VS $(ConfigurationName) variable

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have noticed that `$(ConfigurationName)` is usually the same as `$(Configuration)`. But I cannot find any documentation for what `$(ConfigurationName)` is. Anyone that knows of some documentation of this?

I'm cleaning up in some older build files FYI.

Comment: Mistakes turn into features when they don't get corrected quickly enough.  Looks to me that the Microsoft programmer that worked on sgen.exe got that wrong.  A notorious utility.  The msbuild engineer "fixed" it by ensuring that ConfigurationName is the same as Configuration if it isn't set.  That's fine, no need to ever refer to it yourself.

Comment: I will report this issue, you can also request this on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest). You can also give feedback to github via the link at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022)